# JS Recursive Binary Search - Stackoverflow

Tags: jquery, binary-search, recursive-query

I am trying to run this bubble sort & recursive binary search. However, the output shows "true", "false" or sometimes stating even a "StackOverflow" lol. Could someone help me out with what am I missing? It should output only "true". I believe the error is related to my binary code.

```
function genRandomArray(n) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = Math.round(10 * Math.random());
    }
    return arr;
}
//swap from bubble sort
function swap(array, index1, index2) {
    var saveElement = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = saveElement;
    return array;
}

function bubbleSort(array) {
    var n = array.length;
    for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        var count = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
            if (array[j + 1] < array[j]) {
                count++;
                swap(array, j, j + 1);
            }
        }
        if (count == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return array;
}

function search(array, x, left, right) {
    if (left >= right){
    return false;
    }
    var mid = Math.floor(left+right/2); 
    if (array[mid] == x) {
      return true;
    } 
    else if (array[mid]>x){
        right = mid-1;
    }
    else {
        left = mid+1
    }
    return search(array, x, left, right);
}

function binarySearch(array, x) {
    var n = array.length;
    var right = n;
    var left = 1;
    return search(array, x, left, right);
}

   module.exports = {
    genRandomArray: genRandomArray,
    swap: swap,
    bubbleSort: bubbleSort,
    search: search,
    binarySearch: binarySearch
}

var arr = genRandomArray(6);
console.log(bubbleSort(arr));
console.log(binarySearch(bubbleSort(arr), 4));
```

Comment: Why you need the `left` and `right` variables? Only to find the mid in `var mid = Math.floor(left+right/2);`?

Answer (score 0):

I could fix by refactoring the `search` function, where I slice the smaller leftovers when `mid` is bigger than `x` and the bigger leftovers when `mid` is smaller than `x`, then I create a new array with what's left and call search again.

```
function search(array, x, left, right) {
  console.log(array);
  
  if (array.length == 0) {
    console.log("couldn't find x");
    return false;
  }

  var mid = Math.floor(array.length / 2);

  if (array[mid] == x) {
    return true;

  } else if (array[mid] > x) {
    var newArr = array.slice(0, mid);
    return search(newArr, x);

  } else if (array[mid] < x) {
    var newArr = array.slice(mid + 1, array.length);
    return search(newArr, x);
  }
}
```

I think your issue with StackOverflow was because when you didn't find `x` it was sending the same array over and over again, so it would run into a maximum call stack.